# Avoid printing new line after an input read in C

Tags: c

When getting an input with scanf(), prompt switches to a new line after hitting an `<Enter>`. How can I remain on the same line, after accepting input?

Comment: That's not a question about C. That's the behaviour of your (virtual) *terminal* that you're seeing.

Comment: Turn off local echo in the terminal perhaps. Or you could use a terminal extension such as ncurses, and emit an instruction to reposition the cursor where you want it

Answer (score 0):

If you can make use of [escape sequences](http://www.termsys.demon.co.uk/vtansi.htm) (not portable):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define moveup(x) printf("\033[%zuA", (x))
#define movedn(x) printf("\033[%zuB", (x))
#define movefw(x) printf("\033[%zuC", (x))
#define movebw(x) printf("\033[%zuD", (x))

int main(void)
{
    char str[128];

    scanf("%s", str);
    moveup(1UL);
    movefw(strlen(str));
    fflush(stdout);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

parse your input and when you found '\n' replace it with '\0'

Comment: Deleting the `\n` from the string doesn't cause a move-up cursor.